# Rank formula and supremum of an ordinal.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Sorry for the dumb question, but I still have to get familiarity with this notions.

I have two sets $x$ and $y$ s.t. $x,y\in WF$, I proved that also $\{x\},\{x,y\}\in WF$.

Now I am asked to calculate the rank of $\{x\}$ and of $\{x,y\}$ in terms of $rk(x)$ and of $rk(y)$. This was my thought process:

Using the rank formula I get $rk(\{x\}) = \sup\{rk(z)+1 :z\in\{x\}\} = \sup\{rk(x)+1\} = rk(x)$. But this doesn't seem to be correct since $x\in\{x\} \implies rk(x)<rk(\{x\})$.
Same reasoning for $rk(\{x,y\}$) and I get $rk(\{x,y\}) = \max\{rk(x),rk(y)\}$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Why $\sup\{rk(x)+1\}=rk(x)$? Shouldn't it be $\sup\{rk(x)+1\}=rk(x)+1$?

Comment: The reasoning I made was that since $rk(x)+1$ is a successor ordinal then its sup is its predecessor, i.e. $rk(x)$. I mean, since I get a contradiction I very much suspect that indeed $\text{sup}\{rk(x)+1\}=rk(x) +1 $, but I don't see why.

Comment: When you write $a=\sup\{A\}$ for any set $A$, you mean that $a$ is the least upper bound of $A$ (in the corresponding order). Then, $a$ is an upper bound, this is, for any $x\in A$, we have $x\leq a$. In your case, $A=\{rk(x)+1\}$ and you said that $\sup\{rk(x)+1\}=rk(x)$, then, $rk(x)+1\leq\sup\{rk(x)+1\}=rk(x)$. And this is not true, that's your mistake. In fact, we have $\sup\{rk(x)+1\}=rk(x)+1=rk(\{x\})$.

Comment: Ok, I think I got this. I think my mistake was confusing $\text{sup}\{rk(x)+1\}$ with $\text{sup}(rk(x)+1)$. Where in the first case the set of which I'm considering the supremum is the set that contains as the only element the ordinal $rk(x)+1$, while in the latter I am considering the supremum of the ordinal $rk(x)+1$ itself (in the latter case so I assume I was correct considering $\text{sup}(rk(x)+1) = rk(x)$, right?).

Comment: Yes, I think so. The first case is what you said and, for the latter, I don't use the same notation, but I think that you mean $\sup(rk(x)+1)=\bigcup( rk(x)+1) $. And indeed, $\bigcup( rk(x)+1)=rk(x)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the hints!! Very much appreciated :)